# Plotting proportions of binned values in different groups, without stacking

Tags: r, ggplot2

There may be a very simple solution to my problem but I just can't find it. Please help...

I think the problem is best described with an example. `geom_density()` with `position = "fill"` almost does what I want:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(200)
df <- data.frame(
  value = c(rnorm(100, 0, 1), rnorm(100, 0, 2), rnorm(100, 1, 2)),
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100)
)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5, position = "fill") 

print(p)
```

[image: Stacked proportions]

However, these shapes are stacked ontop of each other. This often makes it difficult to see which group has the highest proportion given a value. But this is what I'm interested in.

Is there any way to plot an "unstacked" version of this, so that lines or shapes are plotted from 0 instead of stacking them on the previous line? I've tried many different things without success. I am not fixed on `geom_density()`, any method that does the trick would be fine.

Comment: Try removing `position = "fill"` from "geom_density()"

Comment: Then the individual values will be plotted but not the proportions of the values in different groups. For the dummy data I provided that might not make a difference but in my real data the total number of values per group are different so I would like to see the proportions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `position="fill"` you could use `after_stat()` to compute the proportions manually which allows for an unstacked version of your chart using `position="identity"`, where I use `ave()` to compute the proportions.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(200)
df <- data.frame(
  value = c(rnorm(100, 0, 1), rnorm(100, 0, 2), rnorm(100, 1, 2)),
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100)
)

ggplot(df, aes(
  x = value, 
  y = after_stat(ave(density, x, FUN = \(x) x / sum(x))),
  fill = group
)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to post an answer with the same output but using dplyr to get the densities into a data frame. This is nicer. I have been using `ave` myself quite a bit inside `aes` recently, and it makes me wonder whether there should be a more elegant mechanism for specifying per-group transformations that need to reference the other groups in the column.

Comment: Compared to the `tapply` approach I used in the past (before I learned about `ave`) using `ave` is already a considerable improvement in elegance for me. :D But I agree. Would be nice to have a kind of out-of-the-box option to specify transformations. Perhaps something along the lines of the `by` aes from `GGally::stat_prop` but more general.

Comment: Thank you so much @stefan, this is exactly what I was looking for! Could you briefly explain how you used ave()?

Comment: Translated to tidyverse syntax, you can think of `ave()` as a `group_by() + mutate()`, i.e. for your case we are doing `data %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(density = density / sum(density))`.